# Using awk to calculate average of each row with different number of columns

Tags: text-processing, awk, command-line

Is it possible to use `awk` to calculate the **average** of each row (with different columns in each row). I have a file like the following, the first column is the names, and I like to calculate the average of each row and print the result in the last column of the input file:

**Input-file** (`data1.csv`):

```
EMPLOYEE1,0.395314,0.384513,,
EMPLOYEE2,5.4908,5.2921,,
EMPLOYEE3,0.0002323,0.00022945,0.00023238,0.00022931
EMPLOYEE4,0.00335516,0.00328432,0.00340309,0.00327163
EMPLOYEE5,1.4816,1.4367,1.4854,1.4353
EMPLOYEE6,7.89E-06,7.93E-06,7.95E-06,7.87E-06
EMPLOYEE7,3.724E-06,3.8745E-06,3.9428E-06,3.7227E-06
EMPLOYEE8,0.699498,0.688892,0.704256,0.683486
EMPLOYEE9,33.5195,31.9736,33.6779,31.742
```

Desired output:

```
EMPLOYEE1,0.395314,0.384513,,,0.3899135
EMPLOYEE2,5.4908,5.2921,,,5.39145
EMPLOYEE3,0.0002323,0.00022945,0.00023238,0.00022931,0.00023086
EMPLOYEE4,0.00335516,0.00328432,0.00340309,0.00327163,0.00332855
EMPLOYEE5,1.4816,1.4367,1.4854,1.4353,1.45975
EMPLOYEE6,7.89E-06,7.93E-06,7.95E-06,7.87E-06,7.91E-06
EMPLOYEE7,3.72E-06,3.87E-06,3.94E-06,3.72E-06,3.82E-06
EMPLOYEE8,0.699498,0.688892,0.704256,0.683486,0.694033
EMPLOYEE9,33.5195,31.9736,33.6779,31.742,32.7282
```

I tried  `awk` like the following, but it doesn't calculate average for  rows with  columns less than maximum NF.

```
awk  -F',' '{ s = 0; for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) s += $i; print $1, (NF > 1) ? s / (NF - 1) : 0; }'  data1.csv
```

and

```
 awk -F','  '{sum=0; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)sum+=$i; print $0,sum/(NF-1)}'  data1.csv
```

But my code doesn't change NF  row. is it possible to change NF  for each row and get desired output?

Comment: your given output doesn't the one from the given input, why the value of the current fields changed? see the differences when applying the [command in my answer below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/672519/72456) and your given output.

Comment: What should the average be given input of `foo,2,,4` (you have different answers making different assumptions about that)? If that can't happen in your input then state that in your question.

Comment: There is no similar structure in my input data, thanks for your feedback. @EdMorton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$ awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '{ 
        s=0; 
        numFields=0; 
        for(i=2; i<=NF;i++){ 
            if(length($i)){ 
                s+=$i; 
                numFields++
            } 
        } 
        print $0, (numFields ? s/numFields : 0)}' data1.csv 
EMPLOYEE1,0.395314,0.384513,,,0.389914
EMPLOYEE2,5.4908,5.2921,,,5.39145
EMPLOYEE3,0.0002323,0.00022945,0.00023238,0.00022931,0.00023086
EMPLOYEE4,0.00335516,0.00328432,0.00340309,0.00327163,0.00332855
EMPLOYEE5,1.4816,1.4367,1.4854,1.4353,1.45975
EMPLOYEE6,7.89E-06,7.93E-06,7.95E-06,7.87E-06,7.91e-06
EMPLOYEE7,3.724E-06,3.8745E-06,3.9428E-06,3.7227E-06,3.816e-06
EMPLOYEE8,0.699498,0.688892,0.704256,0.683486,0.694033
EMPLOYEE9,33.5195,31.9736,33.6779,31.742,32.7282
```

Note that awk prints `0.389914` as the result of `0.779827/2` which means that the average on the first line will be `0.389914` and not `0.389915`. This is because awk will round to the nearest even number and its default print mode (controlled by the `OFMT` variable) is `%0.6g`. If you require more accuracy, you can do:

```
$ awk -F',' -v OFS=',' -v OFMT='%0.7g' '{ 
        s=0; 
        numFields=0; 
        for(i=2; i<=NF;i++){ 
            if(length($i)){ 
                s+=$i; 
                numFields++
            } 
        } 
        print $0, (numFields ? s/numFields : 0)}' data1.csv 
EMPLOYEE1,0.395314,0.384513,,,0.3899135
EMPLOYEE2,5.4908,5.2921,,,5.39145
EMPLOYEE3,0.0002323,0.00022945,0.00023238,0.00022931,0.00023086
EMPLOYEE4,0.00335516,0.00328432,0.00340309,0.00327163,0.00332855
EMPLOYEE5,1.4816,1.4367,1.4854,1.4353,1.45975
EMPLOYEE6,7.89E-06,7.93E-06,7.95E-06,7.87E-06,7.91e-06
EMPLOYEE7,3.724E-06,3.8745E-06,3.9428E-06,3.7227E-06,3.816e-06
EMPLOYEE8,0.699498,0.688892,0.704256,0.683486,0.694033
EMPLOYEE9,33.5195,31.9736,33.6779,31.742,32.72825
```